# C# Getting inherited variables (initialized in "OnActionExecuting") value in child constructor

Tags: c#, inheritance, constructor, controller, onactionexecuting

I have a parent class classA with a variable defined as `public string variable`. This variable var is initialized in the `OnActionExecuting` method defined as `protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext test)` A child class inherits from this class  as `public class classB : classA` However, ths code below fails

```
public class classB : classA{
   string h;
   public classB(){
      h = this.variable
   }
 }
```

That is, the variable var is null. However, if I declare a public  variable variable2 in classA and initialize it on the fly `public string variable2 = "test"`, I can retrieve it in the controller. How can I edit this code so that initialization happening in `OnActionExecuting` can be accessed in the constructor of the inheriting classes?

Comment: `public string var;` so much pain in one line... I think the only way to make that more eye-catching (in a bad way) would be `public String var;` ;p

Comment: sorry, just wanted to shortcut the word variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OnActionExecuting` is invoked **after** the constructor, so: there is no way to get the value of something that *hasn't happened yet*.

If the inheriting class needs a value that is only available when the base-type's `OnActionExecuting` method has fired, then: ***access it then***:

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext ctx)
{
    base.OnActionExecuting(ctx);
    h = this.var;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`OnActionExecuting` most likely is not called in the constructor of `classA`, which means that is called by whoever creates the new instance of `classB`. As such, it will be called only *after* the constructor is run to completion.

So, what you request is not possible.

Think about it:
You can't eat your pizza *before* ordering it.